# Handle List in Redis

Tags: c#, performance, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

A large collection of Master Data (50K records in a list) needs to be cached using Redis. but the application will retrieve single records from master data. Does it make sense to serialize the 50K records in a list and store it in Redis and every time Get the serialized string and deserialize to List object and query using linq and return one data?
e.g.
store

```
IDistributedCache _cache

// data is list<object> of size 50K
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
await _cache.SetStringAsync(key, jsonString, options);
```

retrieve

```
var cachedItem = await _cache.GetStringAsync(key);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(cachedItem);
...
return result.where(x=>x.Id=id)
```

because the DeserializeObject of a large string is not efficient. If I store one by one in redis and if there is a requirement to also needs to be stored as whole then I am worried there will be a data duplication storing same data twice. so thats why I prefer to store 50K as whole.

any advice?

Comment: it would be an overkill

Comment: store each item separately in cache by indexing on id as cache key if that works in your scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage:

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(cachedItem);
...
return result.where(x=>x.Id=id)
```

strongly suggests that something very inefficient is happening here. If you want to be able to fetch by a key, the more obvious model here would be a redis *hash*, using the `Id` as the key, and the serialized payload for each value (`HashSet[Async]`). Then you can fetch, add, update or remove indivudual elements individually; you can also still get everything if needed (`HashGetAll[Async]`/`HashScan[Async]`).

You could also store each item *individually* (`StringSet[Async]`) using the id *as part of the key*, but if you do that, then there is no good mechanism to get the entire list.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but I don't this IDistributedCache supports HashSet, HashGetAll, HashScan

Comment: I see we need to use the IConnectionMultiplexer?

Comment: @Hulk and where in your question did you cite `IDistributedCache`? I see a tag for [tag:stackexchange.redis], which is the API I used here...

Comment: @Hulk if you're limited to that API, you'd have to use features *supported* by that API, which means either store the entire list, or store per record; frankly neither is a great option, so you need to decide: accept the limitations of those options, or use the wider set of redis features that exist, but which require you to use a different API; either approach is valid, and only you can decide

Comment: Why can't we consider using Redis list data type here?

Comment: @JaydeepSuryawanshi redis lists aren't keyed - they're indexed positionally; the question here was about fetching a subitem by *key* (`Id`). Lists wouldn't help with that, but a hash where the `Id` is used as the hash key: absolutely would